# VBA Copy data to separate pages with loop

Tags: vba, excel

I think i am staring at it too much, but i can't seem to figure out what I did wrong. I have a page with 3 different lists on it like this:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/yHyA9]

what i am trying to do is make a loop that looks at how much items are on the list, and then copies each line on a separate worksheet. so sheet 2 has the data of B2, C2, D2 & E2, sheet 3 has B3, C3, D3 & E3, etcetra.

here is my code:

```
Sub testLoopCustom()

Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Dim sht4 As Worksheet
Dim sht5 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb1 = wb.Sheets("source")
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("sheet2")
Set sht3 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
Set sht4 = wb.Sheets("Sheet4")
Set sht5 = wb.Sheets("Sheet5")


'Find the last row (in column A) with data.
LastRow = wb1.Range("B:B").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
i = 2

'This is the beginning of the loop
For i = 2 To LastRow
    'First sheet
    sht2.Range("A2") = wb1.Range("B" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("B2") = wb1.Range("C" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("C2") = wb1.Range("D" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("D2") = wb1.Range("E" & i).Value
    i = i + 1

    'Second sheet
    sht3.Range("A2") = wb1.Range("B" & i).Value
    sht3.Range("B2") = wb1.Range("C" & i).Value
    sht3.Range("C2") = wb1.Range("D" & i).Value
    sht3.Range("D2") = wb1.Range("E" & i).Value
    i = i + 1

    'Third sheet
    sht4.Range("A2") = wb1.Range("B" & i).Value
    sht4.Range("B2") = wb1.Range("C" & i).Value
    sht4.Range("C2") = wb1.Range("D" & i).Value
    sht4.Range("D2") = wb1.Range("E" & i).Value
    i = i + 1

    'Second sheet
    sht5.Range("A2") = wb1.Range("B" & i).Value
    sht5.Range("B2") = wb1.Range("C" & i).Value
    sht5.Range("C2") = wb1.Range("D" & i).Value
    sht5.Range("D2") = wb1.Range("E" & i).Value
    i = i + 1


Next i

End Sub
```

the annoying part is that it worked before i changed "something" and now it doesn't anymore... It now only copies the last line into the first sheet.

Can anyone see my mistake? 
and bonus question: can the loop be simplyfied so that it automatically goes to the next sheet as well?

Comment: At a fast review I detected that you are not declaring `sht2, sht3, sht4` and `sht5` variables.

Comment: That was indeed true, but changing that didn't fix the problem alas. updated the code.

Comment: Every time you go through the loop, you are overwriting `sht2.Range("A2")` etc.

Comment: Why you are adding `i = i + 1` at the end of a block without let the `For Loop` do it by itself? I think you are skipping some rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as though when 'i' finally increments to equal 'LastRow', it will write the First Sheet with LastRow's data, increment past the value of 'LastRow' (i = i + 1) and attempt to write the remaining sheets with the blank cells that exist beyond the LastRow.  Then the loop is exited because i > LastRow by 4.

Looks like you are trying to flatten the source worksheets data into separate sheets, one line each.  Using a loop:

```
Dim workSht As Worksheet
For i = 2 To LastRow

    Set workSht = wb.Sheets("Sheet" & i)

    workSht.Range("A2") = wb1.Range("B" & i).Value
    workSht.Range("B2") = wb1.Range("C" & i).Value
    workSht.Range("C2") = wb1.Range("D" & i).Value
    workSht.Range("D2") = wb1.Range("E" & i).Value

Next i
```

Comment: it gives subscript out of range

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For i = 2 to LastRow

    Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Range("A2").Value = wb1.Range("B" & i).value
    Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Range("B2").Value = wb1.Range("C" & i).value
    Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Range("C2").Value = wb1.Range("D" & i).value
    Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Range("D2").Value = wb1.Range("E" & i).value

Next
```

As you loop through the rows it will place each row onto the sheet with the corresponding row number in the name.

Comment: I get subscript out of range

Comment: on which line @perbrethil? are you sheet names the same as you provided in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do your code like this:

```
sht2.Range("A" & i) = wb1.Range("A" & i).Value
sht2.Range("B" & i) = wb1.Range("B" & i).Value
sht2.Range("C" & i) = wb1.Range("C" & i).Value
sht2.Range("D" & i) = wb1.Range("D" & i).Value
```

Thus on every sheet you would get a copy from `wb1`. Another option is the usage of `Offset()` like this:

```
sht2.Range("A2").Offset(i - 2, 0) = wb1.Range("A" & i).Value
sht2.Range("B2").Offset(i - 2, 0) = wb1.Range("B" & i).Value
sht2.Range("C2").Offset(i - 2, 0) = wb1.Range("C" & i).Value
```

depending on what exactly do you need and how do you feel more comfortable.

[MSDN Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel)

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is copy each row to a new sheet, then this will work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim SourceWS As Worksheet
    Dim Headers As Range
    Dim SourceData As Range
    Dim DataRow As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set SourceWS = wb.Sheets("Source")
    Set Headers = SourceWS.Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Resize(1)
    Set SourceData = SourceWS.Range("B2", SourceWS.Cells(SourceWS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    If SourceData.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data

    For Each DataRow In SourceData.Cells
        With wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
            Headers.Copy
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            DataRow.Resize(, Headers.Columns.Count).Copy .Range("A2")
        End With
    Next DataRow

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Great but it works a little bit too nice. what i want is to copy the 4 separate data on different cells, the coords next to each other are just so i dont make the example what i was trying to do too difficult. also the pages already exist and this just opens more and more tabs

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take this approach.

```
The range for the code example below looks like this
Column A : Header in A1 = Country, A2:A? = Country names
Column B : Header in B1 = Name, B2:B? = Names
Column C : Header in C1 = Gender, C2:C? = F or M
Column D : Header in D1 = Birthday, D2:D? = Dates
```

1: Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range. You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))

2: Filter and set the filter field and the filter criteria:This example filter on the first column in the range (change the field if needed). In this case the range starts in A so Field 1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
Use "<>Netherlands" as criteria if you want the opposite
My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Netherlands"

3:Important:This macro call a function named LastRow
You find this function below the macro, copy this function together with the macro in a standard module

In the code you see four filter examples that you can use, we use example 1 in this macro and I commented the other 3 examples in the code.
1: Criteria in the code (=Netherlands, see the tips below the macro)
2: Filter on ActiveCell value
3: Filter on Range value (D1 in this example)
4: Filter on InputBox value

```
Sub Copy_With_AutoFilter1()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim FilterCriteria As String
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim rng As Range

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Filter and set the filter field and the filter criteria :
    'This example filter on the first column in the range (change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field 1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    'Use "<>Netherlands" as criteria if you want the opposite
    My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Netherlands"

    'If you want to filter on a cell value you can use this, use "<>" for the opposite
    'This example uses the activecell value
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & ActiveCell.Value

    'This will use the cell value from A2 as criteria
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Range("A2").Value

    ''If you want to filter on a Inputbox value use this
    'FilterCriteria = InputBox("What text do you want to filter on?", _
     '                              "Enter the filter item.")
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & FilterCriteria

    'Check if there are not more then 8192 areas(limit of areas that Excel can copy)
    CCount = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    If CCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas:" _
             & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
             & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to worksheet"
    Else
        'Add a new Worksheet
        Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index))

        'Ask for the Worksheet name
        sheetName = InputBox("What is the name of the new worksheet?", _
                             "Name the New Sheet")

        On Error Resume Next
        WSNew.Name = sheetName
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Change the name of sheet : " & WSNew.Name & _
                 " manually after the macro is ready. The sheet name" & _
                 " you fill in already exists or you use characters" & _
                 " that are not allowed in a sheet name."
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Copy/paste the visible data to the new worksheet
        My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
        With WSNew.Range("A1")
            ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
            ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Select
        End With

        ' If you want to delete the rows that you copy, also use this
        ' With My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range
        '     On Error Resume Next
        '     Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) _
        '               .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        '     On Error GoTo 0
        '     If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
        ' End With

    End If

    'Close AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    If Not WSNew Is Nothing Then WSNew.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```